# getting profit in array without using loops

Tags: c++, c++11

I have something like this in tradeTest.cpp

```
int main() {
    vector<int> prices{38, 28, 30, 38, 34};

    int profit = bestProfit(prices.begin(), prices.end());

    if (profit == 10) {
        cout << "Profit of 10 is correct\n";
    } else {
        cout << "Profit of " << profit << " is incorrect\n";
    }
}
```

and currently this in trade.h

```
template <class Iterator>
int Profit (Iterator begin, Iterator end)
{

}
```

What I want to do is buy low and sell high without the possibility of going back.

Thanks for your itme.

Comment: If they were sorted. Then the low price would be `*begin` and the high price would be `*(end - 1)`

Comment: @Carcigenicate sorry, I edited the question what I meant is sell high. Thanks

Comment: @LokiAstari they are not sorted

Comment: Have you used lambda with the sort algo

Comment: You can go back. There’s nothing stopping you from copying the begin iterator and iterating multiple times.

Comment: @justewe3 If only there was a way to do that!

Comment: Think about it. If you just iterate sequentially one time, how are you going to know to buy at 18 if you don't know if any subsequent values are lower, or sell at 26 if you don't know if any subsequent values are higher? Obviously, you are going to have to sort the input first, or iterate multiple times

Comment: @JakeFreeman yes, I think I need to use those two but not sure how

Comment: Also, you have a random access iterator, you can go backwards with those too. You can access all elements of the array withour limitation.

Comment: `numel=std::distance(begin,end)`, and `*(begin+n)`.

Comment: justewe why not just plug it right into the sort method which is part of algo header

Comment: @CrisLuengo: sure, logically, in this example, the iterators are random-access.  But the function doesn't know that, unless that is stipulated as an input requirement, or even forced using SFINAE via `std::enable_if` and `std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::iterator_category`, etc.

Comment: Ah, you just changed that. Ok.

Comment: @CrisLuengo It was wrong, sorry. I just added it in the question

Comment: Still you can copy the iterator and iterate multiple times. I would probably loop over all elements, and for each loop over the remaining elements. If you buy at that time, what is the max profit you can get? Then accumulate the max over all start times. O(n^2), but who cares?

Comment: @CrisLuengo how to copy the iterator ?

Comment: `auto it = begin`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo can u post something I begin with if u don't want to post the answer. I am still now sure how copying the iterator will help.

Comment: I’m typing on a phone, but I could try to write a quick answer...

Comment: @CrisLuengo that will be much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way to do what you want would be with adding an `int max = 0` parameter:

```
template <class Iterator>
int bestProfit (Iterator begin, Iterator end, int max = 0)
{
    if(begin==end)
    {
        return max;
    }else
    {
        int p = *std::max_element(begin+1, end) - *begin;
        max = std::max(max, p);        
        return bestProfit(begin+1, end, max);
    }

}

int main() {
    vector<int> prices{28, 18, 20, 26, 24};

    int profit = bestProfit(prices.begin(), prices.end());

    if (profit == 8) {
        cout << "Profit of 8 is correct\n";
    } else {
        cout << "Profit of " << profit << " is incorrect\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: As I said on the other answer, sorting doesnt solve the problem.

Comment: This is wrong the profit is 10 while it should be 26-18 = 8

Comment: @CrisLuengo this sorted allows you to get the highest and lowest value. Sorting is the solution is correct

Comment: @justewe3 28 is the highest and 18 is the lowest perhaps you should tell us what 26 is

Comment: @JakeFreeman the thing is that u can't go back on time. I mentioned it in the question. So once u buy u must sell in the future ( the numbers after the number that u buy (

Comment: If you sort the values, you lose temporal relationship. If the highest values is the first and the lowest value is the last, their difference is not how much profit you can make.

Comment: @justewe3 updated my answer to efficiently do your task without sort or for loops

Comment: That’s quite nice and compact. +1

Comment: Actually, come to think of it, this buys lowest, but not necessarily at the point of max return. What if the lowest point is the last? You make 0 profit!

Comment: @CrisLuengo Then the max is the min because it is the elements in the range of the index of the min and the end. The OP requires buying at the lowest point. Just confirmed it returns 0.

Comment: Say the input is 1,2,3,4,5,0. Your answer is 0, but max profit is 4.

Comment: @CrisLuengo is right, if the lowest is in the end. Then it should buy at 20 and sell at 26

Comment: @JakeFreeman although this is not working all the times but it is the best form the posted ones. Thanks for the answer

Comment: @justewe3 I am working on a recursive version which will work in all cases.

Comment: @JakeFreeman I am allowed to only use one function. I am not sure if that will be possible with only one function ( bestProfit )

Comment: @justewe3 could I modify what parameters it takes?

Comment: @justewe3 I made it into a recursive function using crisLuengo function and modified it

Comment: @CrisLuengo thank you I used you function to make my recursive function.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>As I suggested in the comments, you might want to do something like this. Sorry I can’t test right now, no guarantees!</strike>

```
template <class Iterator>
int bestProfit (Iterator begin, Iterator end)
{
  int profit = 0;
  for(;begin!=end; ++begin){
    int p = *std::max_element(begin+1, end) - *begin;
    profit = std:max(profit, p);
  }
  return profit;
}
```

Could also be quite elegant with a recursive function, as suggested somewhere in a comment.

The code above should probably skip the last loop iteration, come to think of it. What does `std::max_element` return if both input iterators are identical?

### EDIT:

You already have a working and accepted answer, but just for completeness sake (I guess I'm stubborn like that) here's my version of the recursive function. This does not have any *explicit* loops, but there is a loop inside of `std::max_element`, and recursive functions a way of writing a loop. There is no way to visit all elements in a vector or list without a loop!

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

// Look mama! No `for`!
template <class Iterator>
int bestProfit (Iterator begin, Iterator end)
{
  int buy = *begin;
  ++begin;
  if (begin == end) return 0; // no profit to be had
  int sell = *std::max_element(begin, end);
  int profit = sell - buy; // max profit if we buy now
  return std::max(profit, bestProfit(begin, end)); // will we do better if we wait?
}

int main() {
  std::vector<int> prices1{38, 28, 30, 38, 34};
  if (bestProfit(prices1.begin(), prices1.end()) != 10)
    std::cout << "bad 1!\n";

  std::vector<int> prices2{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0};
  if (bestProfit(prices2.begin(), prices2.end()) != 4)
    std::cout << "bad 2!\n";

  std::vector<int> prices3{2, 3, 1, 4, 5, 0};
  if (bestProfit(prices3.begin(), prices3.end()) != 4)
    std::cout << "bad 3!\n";

  std::vector<int> prices4{0, 1, 2, 5, 4, 3};
  if (bestProfit(prices4.begin(), prices4.end()) != 5)
    std::cout << "bad 4!\n";

  std::vector<int> prices5{100, 200, 0, 1, 3};
  if (bestProfit(prices5.begin(), prices5.end()) != 100)
    std::cout << "bad 5!\n";

  std::vector<int> prices6{100, 200, 0, 101, 30};
  if (bestProfit(prices6.begin(), prices6.end()) != 101)
    std::cout << "bad 6!\n";
}
```

Comment: I tried it out but I am getting this error `error: cannot convert ‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >’ to ‘int’ in initialization
` and it is pointing at `*begin;` Any idea of how to fix it ?

Comment: Ah, makes sense, sorry, I’ll fix it. It needs a dereference.

Comment: I think this dereferneces the end iterator in the last loop iteration. I need a better screen to do this right :/

Comment: I've just realised that you are using a for loop, the question is saying **without using imperative loop**

Comment: Thanks for the answer though, it works great but it is using a for loop

Comment: I guess you need to recode it as a recursive function then. That’s the sneaky way of looping...

Comment: The problem is that I need to use only one function, so recursion is much of help

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple divine and Conquer algorithm. And also you haven't described the problem correctly i think, sorting the array is wrong. Cause 18-28 will be the maximum but you can't buy at 18 and sell at 28 if the array is at that order

Comment: Also really before asking stack overflow open your algorithm's book. This is a classic problem for cs universities in algorithms

Comment: get a life bro.